# Excel, Lookup output colum depending on another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I currently have lookup function that takes a code, looks for it on a specific column and gives me a price value on a specific column based on the code. I use this function many times, for different months, but soon I will have different output information for certain months and it will keep changing.

So what I need is a way for the lookup function to take into consideration the code and the date (that will be a few rows before the lookup function), so that the output column with the prices is selected based on the date, and then based on the code I get the right price.

Instead of having one column with prices I'll have many, and which one to look in will depend on the date. So I need to adjust that lookup formula.

Any help will be apreciated, as always, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a Vlookup or a similar technique, you can change the formula to look up the column based on the date.

A non-dynamic formula would use a hard-coded column number, like

`=VLOOKUP(B2,$E$1:$I$5,2,FALSE)`

You need to make the column number (the `2` in this formula) dynamic.

Consider the screenshot below.

The formula in cell C2 is `=VLOOKUP(B2,$E$1:$I$5,MATCH(YEAR(A2),$E$1:$I$1,0),FALSE)` copied down.

It will return the price from the year columns, based on the date in column A. The Match function uses the year of the date in column A and then looks for that year in the first row of the lookup table. It returns the number of the column with the matching year.

[image]

Comment: I think I wasn't clear enough.  The table I got, representing the table on the right of your screenshot is something like that, but the dates it has are specific months that have different prices. Those prices represent the price from that month until the next change.                                                                                                            Then on the left table what I got is the month and year such as Oct-15 on the top row (From 2014 to 2021). Then some data and formulas that gives me the code at the bottom for each month. Having that code I need the price.

Comment: For that specific month and article. This would be so much easier if I could post those screenshots, is there any tutorial on how I could do that?

Comment: post a sample file or screenshot on one of the gazillion file sharing services and then edit your question and post a link. Post a comment when you've done that.